# Getting only hour/minute of datetime

Tags: c#

Using C#, I have a `datetime` object, but all I want is the hour and the minutes from it in a datetime object.

So for example:
if I have a `DateTime` object of `July 1 2012 12:01:02` All I want is `July 1 2012 12:01:00` in the `datetime` object (so, no seconds).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this:

```
var src = DateTime.Now;
var hm = new DateTime(src.Year, src.Month, src.Day, src.Hour, src.Minute, 0);
```

Answer (score 79):

Try this:

```
String hourMinute = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Now you will get the time in hour:minute format.

Comment: This is the best answer. The ToString method for DateTime is to be used just for that purpose: To format the datetime. See [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: OP asked for a DateTime object, not string.

Comment: Technically not an answer to the OP - but it was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 38):

Just use `Hour` and `Minute` properties

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
date.Hour;
date.Minute;
```

Or you can easily zero the seconds using

```
var zeroSecondDate = date.AddSeconds(-date.Second);
```

Comment: He did say "in a DateTime object"... :)

Comment: @zomkyns We can easily zero seconds with less code than creating new instance

Comment: @Ribtoks, DateTime is a struct and is immutable. By using AddSeconds it creates a new instance of a DateTime and returns that in its place. So either way, you'll be creating a new DateTime object. AddSeconds eventually ends up calling `return new DateTime((UInt64)(ticks + value) | InternalKind)` (looked at .net source - reference only).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend keeping the object you have, and just utilizing the properties that you want, rather than removing the resolution you already have.

If you want to print it in a certain format you may want to look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)...That way you can preserve your resolution further down the line.

That being said you can create a new `DateTime` object using only the properties you want as @romkyns has in his answer.